how to solve this type of probleme with flutter and firebase
Hello everyone i'm trying to connect my app web flutter to firebase storage to get all the images stored by a raspberry pi webcam, and that show me this errors :
can anyone help please <3 :
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/firebase_app.dart:18:25: Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'.
    FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_web-2.8.10/lib/src/utils/web_utils.dart:71:13: Error: Method not found: 'FallThroughError'.
      throw FallThroughError();
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.7.7/lib/src/platform_interface/utils/load_bundle_task_state.dart:13:13: Error: Method not found: 'FallThroughError'.
      throw FallThroughError();
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed to compile application.


Here is the solution:
run these commands in terminal:

flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
dart pub outdated


The errors you're encountering are related to the version incompatibility between the Firebase packages you're using and the Flutter version you're working with.
flutter clean
flutter pub cache repair
